# Symfony local web server not detecting env variable

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony's local web server and whenever I use it, it doesn't seem to detect all of the environment variables in the .env file and I'm lost on why that is.

This is what I see when I load the website:

[image: error screen]

if I type the command

`php bin/console debug:dotenv`

I see everything I expect.

I'm lost on why this isn't working and hoping someone can help me understand what I'm possibly doing wrong.

Comment: Just a guess, but are the variables in your `.env` file actually referenced as parameters in your `services.yaml` config file? According to the Symfony docs, the `debug:container --env-vars` command shows "all environment variables, with their values, referenced in Symfony's container configuration." So I'm guessing it would only show variables actually being used for configuration.

Comment: no it's just in the .env file.

Comment: Okay.  Avoid getenv when using the Symfony framework.  You want to tweak the constructor and inject JWT_Public.  The docs have plenty of examples.  And just for future info, avoid images.  Hard to read and even harder to copy from.  Paste the relevant text inside a code block.

Comment: so I should instead use parameters in service.yml? If you could provide an example that'd be awesome (even if it's just a link from symfony). it must have changed recently because it used to work just fine.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now, guess it's a new thing they did (I did take a small break from symfony work so guess I was bound to lose track of important changes like that). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit more research on this because I was confused by the fact that $_ENV had the variables but getenv did not.  There is a [discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/49928) on this topic with more details.  Bottom line is that using putenv/getenv is not threadsafe and can cause problems for certain Apache configurations.

However it is possible to tell Symfony to use putenv assuming you accept the risk.  It is part of the [runtime](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/runtime.html#using-options) component.

Updating composer.json will do the trick.

```
    "extra": {
        "runtime": {
            "use_putenv": true
        },
```

Be sure to run `composer dump-autoload` after editing composer.json so your changes get reflected in vendor/autoload_runtime.php

Needless to say you should still be injecting your variables but if you really need to use getenv (perhaps legacy code) then this is how you can do it.

Comment: I appreciate you telling me this, I tried looking around and didn't see anything hinting to this. I'll just follow how they prefer it as it's sounds like the better way.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that since you're not referencing the env variables in your Symfony config anywhere, they aren't loaded into the container configuration which is why they aren't listed when using the `debug:container --env-vars` command.

Try adding a parameter to your `services.yaml` that references one of the "missing" env variables then recheck `debug:container --env-vars` to see if it shows up. Something like:

```
# services.yaml
parameters:
    app.foo: '%env(MISSING_ENV_VAR)%'
```

[Symfony docs: listing environment variables](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#listing-environment-variables)

Comment: my complaints is more when I load up the app using the local web server it's not detecting any of the envs

Comment: @Eman Are you getting some sort of error message? If so consider updating your question showing how you define the variable and how you are trying to use it.  Right now all we know is that --env-vars is not working as you expected.

Comment: I get an error that something is empty and when I see what line its a getenv() line meaning it's not detecting my .env file.

Comment: If you could edit your question to include the error you're seeing that would be helpful.