# Avoid hardcoded values in Symfony

Tags: symfony, environment-variables

I have a `Product` entity and a `Brand` entity.

A product can have multiple brands; so let's take a Product P having Brand B1 and B2.
One of these brands, B1, is a "main" brand.

I want to know if a product has a certain brand in the Product entity (like a getter / isser) and especially if the product belongs to the main brand.

I have a `env()` helper to set the IDs of each brands depending on the environments, so I can do :

```
public function isB1Product(): bool
{
    foreach ($this->brands as $brand) {
        if ($brand->getId() === (int)env('B1_ID') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Do you know if there is another way to achieve this ?
I don't want to harcode values (the brands' name can change at anytime).

Thanks !

Comment: Lookup `symfony container parameters` which will show you how to inject constants.  However, method names like `isB1Product` make this seem a bit useless.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to inject parameters and so env vars in services or controllers. However, hwo can I use my env vars in entities ? Also, can you tell me what is wrong with this kind of methods ? Thanks ! :)

Comment: Entities are not services and thus are not amenable to having stuff injected into them.  There are some workarounds typically involving doctrine events but they tend to be a bit hackish.  Try moving the checking code into a service and then pass the entity as an argument.  As far as what is wrong with this kind of method?  It was the name I was objecting to.  If you are trying to avoid hard-coding `B1` then having `B1` as part of the method name seems curious.

Comment: It is also possible to expose your env variables and access them through [getenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75915630/symfony-local-web-server-not-detecting-env-variable/75959287#75959287).  It is not the `Symfony\Doctrine` way of doing things but it might work for your case.

Comment: You could also consider setting [class constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183604/how-use-service-yml-set-public-static-propery-of-class/76184558#76184558) dynamically.  Again, not the normal Symfony way of doing things but it might work for you.

Comment: so far, it sounds like an XY-Problem. I have yet to understand, why you need to define any constants or brands or check for them, really. Avoiding hard-coding stuff usually means, storing meta-data somewhere. Like on the brand entity, there could be a property "priority" or "isDefault" or anything. What is the semantics on why this brand / product is "more important" than other brands/products. if you have a brand you want to check for, you could just have Product.belongsTo(Brand) and do almost the same check. having functions for every brand sounds ... weird.

Comment: Would a method like this be better `hasBrand(string $brand)` this way you can use it in your services and dynamically check for any brand you like.

Comment: I can not have a `hasBrand(string $brand)` because I don't want to hardcode brands' names (here, the function parameter)...

Comment: Can't you add a boolean property to your brand entity that keeps track of whether a brand is a main brand?

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface for the product type. That way it will still reflect the business logic while not hardcoding the value directly, and it can be useable anywhere you want in the code.

```php
interface ProductTypeA{
    public const NAME = 'A';
}

interface ProductTypeB{
    public const NAME = 'B';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

I can't use interfaces because the data is stored in database, so I don't know which data can be stored.

I realize that my `isB1Product()` method name does not reflect what I really want; rather `isMainProduct()` knowing that B1 is the main brand.

Anyway, I find a solution writing a `env()` helper function -as in Laravel.

Thanks to all !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).