# Symfony 6.3 is not reading my .env-file, what do I need to do?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I created a **Symfony 6.3 application** and just came across the issue, that ENV-variables will not be loaded from the local ".env"-file

I have a file ".env" in the projects root directory with many ENV-variables included:

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=debug
APP_SECRET=s3c3t5678
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###
TEST=test1234
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://s.....******"
```

Config-File `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

However, not all variables will be included into the Kernel.

Running the command

```bash
php bin/console debug:container --env-vars
```

will only list the very first ENV-variable: APP_ENV.

Thus, the application is not able to find the database because DATABASE_URL will not be detected.

The command:

```
php bin/console debug:dotenv
```

is instead showing all ENV-vars from `.env`:

```
APP_ENV      | debug
APP_SECRET   | s3c3...
DATABASE_URL | postgres://host...
```

```
ls -laH .env
```

shows:

```
.env
.env.local
.env.test
```

For unknown reasons, the migration commands for doctrine will read all entries properly and connect to the right database, reading DATABASE_URL, as it connects to the database successfuly and even runs migration.

The issues:

1. doctrine migration are reading the .env-file properly,
2. the App Kernel not.

I'm running **Symfony 6.3**:

```
    "symfony/asset": "6.3.*",
    "symfony/cache": "6.3.*",
    "symfony/console": "6.3.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "6.3.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^2",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.3.*",
```

What happens here?

Comment: Hi. Can you include output of this command `php bin/console debug:dotenv`? and check all .env* files (`ls -lah .env*`) . Thanks

Comment: Thanks @SilvioQ, I added the requested information

Comment: `php bin/console debug:dotenv` shows all env variables declared, but `php bin/console debug:container --env-vars` only list env variables compiled in your kernel. So, your app is not using DATABASE_URL env var, although it is declared in .env files (or in your environment space). Maybe you is not using doctrine dbal default_conection yet.

Comment: There might be some useful info in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75915630/10664489